# Covering the primes by arithmetic progressions

Tags: arithmetic-progression, prime-numbers, open-problems

Define the *length* of a set of arithmetic progressions
of natural numbers
$A=\lbrace A_1, A_2, \ldots \rbrace$
to be $\min_i | A_i |$: the length of the shortest sequence
among all the progressions.
Say that $A$ *exactly covers* a set $S$
if $\bigcup_i A_i = S$.
Let $P'$ be the primes excluding 2.

> What is the longest set of arithmetic progressions
>   that exactly covers the primes $P'$?

In other words, I want to maximize the length of
a set of such arithmetic progressions.
Call this maximum $L_{\max}$.

$L_{\max} \ge 2$ because
$$
P' \;=\;
\lbrace 3,5 \rbrace
\cup
\lbrace 7,11 \rbrace
\cup
\cdots
\cup
\lbrace 521,523 \rbrace
\cup
\cdots
$$
Perhaps it is possible that
$$P' \;=\;
\lbrace 3, 11, 19 \rbrace 
\cup 
\lbrace 5, 17, 29,41,53 \rbrace
\cup
\lbrace 7,19,31,43 \rbrace
\cup
\cdots
\;,$$
but I cannot get far with sequences of length $\ge 3$.
(I know Green-Tao establishes that there are arbitrarily
long arithmetic progressions in $P$, but I don't know
if that helps with my question.)

I am number-theoretically naïve,
and apologize if this question is nonsensical or trivial.
In any case, I appreciate the tutoring!

**Addendum**. Although my question should be revised (as Idoneal suggests)
in light of George Lowther's proof that 3
cannot be in a progression of length 4, George has shown that it is likely that $L_{\max}=3$
but certification requires resolving an open problem.  So I've added the *open-problem* tag.
Thanks for everyone's interest!

Comment: some general heuristics and explicit hard conjectures suggest that you may cover primes by (even disjoint) arithmetic progressions of arbitrary length $n$. Indeed, if you have already covered all primes up to $p$ (but not $p$), then there must exist an arithmetic progression $\{\p,p+d,p+2d,\dots,p+(n-1)d}$ for infinitely many $d$'s. So cover $p$ and proceed.

Comment: @Fedor: Your comment seems to definitively answer my question: $L_{\max}$ has no upper bound! I did not know the existence result you use.  Thanks!

Comment: it is not a result, but rather widely open conjecture...

Comment: As Fedor suggests, the question "does every prime belong to an arithmetic progression of primes of length $d$," to which this question is equivalent, is very, very open for large $d$.  So this question should probably be re-tagged "open-question"; that said this statistic is probably an interesting one for many other subsets of the integers.

Comment: @Fedor, Daniel: Oh, I see, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @Daniel: How about d=3. Is that open?

Comment: The use of the word, "exactly", together with the examples given, suggests to me that you want disjoint progressions. If that's the case, then I don't think it's quite equivalent to the question about primes belonging to progressions. E.g., if $p\lt q\lt r$ are prime, and the only 3-term progression containing $q$ is $p,q,2q-p$, and the only 3-term progression containing $r$ is $p,r,2r-p$, then you're sunk, no? 

Comment: @Gerry: I did mean cover and not partition,
as my second example illustrated (19 is repeated).
But I see and appreciate your point.

Comment: @Joseph, I missed that 19. 

Comment: @Joseph:  Ah oops.  

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Despite the comments to the question (including mine), this is a bit easier than it seems at first sight. We can show that $L_{\max}=2$ or $3$. Almost certainly we have $L_\max=3$. However, determining which of these is actually the case seems to be beyond current technology, according to this MO answer "[Are all primes in a PAP-3?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34197/are-all-primes-in-a-pap-3/34298#34298)".

Showing that, $L_{\max} < 4$ is easy. That is, not every odd prime is contained in an arithmetic progression of primes of length 4. More specifically, 3 is not contained in an arithmetic progression of length 4. Suppose that $\lbrace x, x+d, x+2d, x+3d \rbrace$ was such a progression for $d > 0$. Then $x\not=2$, otherwise we would have $x=2,d=1$, but $x+2d=4$ is not prime. So, $x=3$. But, then, $x+3d=3(1+d)$ is not prime.

Edit: Looking at $\tilde L_\max \equiv \max_A\liminf_i \vert A_i\vert$ might be more interesting. I expect that this is infinite but, again, showing that $\tilde L_\max > 2$ appears to be beyond current means.

Comment: I think maybe, in his comment, Fedor was suggesting that it can be done using arithmetic progressions with arbitrarily large step size, rather than arbitrarily large length.

Comment: @George: Clever proof that 3 is not in a progression of length 4!
Similarly 5 is not in a progression of length 6. So the question could be modified to ask for coverage of all but the beginning of the sequence.  But I won't attempt to reformulate the question in light of your recognizing that deciding between 2 and 3 is already "beyond the current technology" (a useful [and optimistic!] phrase).

Comment: I can't claim credit for that phrase, as I was just quoting Ben Green's linked answer.

Comment: In such problems, it is interesting to ignore the small primes and ask what happens for all sufficiently large primes. Perhaps that is what Fedor had meant.

Comment: No no, I meant what I said, but I've been mistaken, sorry. The natural conjecture is that $p$ lies in arithmetic progression of length $p$, but of course not more, by trivial reasons (modulo $p$). So, most probably we may cover all primes but finite number of them by arithmetic progressiond of arbitrary length.