# The topology of Arithmetic Progressions of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, prime-numbers, simplicial-complexes

The primary motivation for this question is the following: I would like to extract some topological statistics which capture how arithmetic progressions of prime numbers "fit together" in a manner that will be made precise below.

### Setup

Consider a nested family of simplicial complexes $K(p)$ indexed by prime $p \in \mathbb N$ defined as follows:

1. the vertices are all odd primes less than or equal to $p$, and
2. insert a $d$-simplex ($d \geq 2$) spanning $d+1$ vertices if and only if they constitute an arithmetic progression. Of course, one must also insert all faces, and faces-of-faces etc. so that the defining property of a simplicial complex is preserved.

For instance, $K(7)$ has the vertices $3,5,7$ and a single $2$-simplex $(3,5,7)$ along with all its faces. $K(11)$ has all this, plus the vertex $11$ and the simplex $(3,7,11)$. The edge $(3,7)$ already exists so only the other two need to be added. Thus, the fact that $(3,7)$ occurs in two arithmetic progressions bounded by $11$ is encoded by placing the corresponding edge in the boundary of two 2-simplices.

### Question

Has someone already defined and studied this complex? What I am mostly interested in is

> How does the homology of $K(p)$ change with $p$?

If it helps, here are -- according to home-brew computations -- the statistics for the first few primes (Betti 0 and 1 over $\mathbb{Z}_2$). I've already confirmed that the sequence of Betti-1's is not in Sloane's online encyclopedia of integer sequences. If an intermediate K[p] is missing in the list, that means that the homology is the same as that for the previous prime.

K [3]: 1 0
 K [5]: 2 0
 K [7]: 1 0
 K [13]: 2 0
 K [17]: 2 1
 K [19]: 1 2
 K [23]: 1 4
 K [31]: 1 6
 K [37]: 2 6
 K [43]: 1 7
 K [53]: 1 8
 K [59]: 1 9
 K [61]: 1 10
 K [67]: 1 12
 K [71]: 1 17
 K [73]: 1 20
 K [79]: 1 23
 K [83]: 1 26
 K [89]: 1 31
 K [97]: 1 32
 K [101]: 1 35
 K [103]: 1 41
 K [107]: 1 43
 K [109]: 1 47
 K [113]: 1 53
 K [127]: 1 58
 K [131]: 1 62
 K [137]: 1 67
 K [139]: 1 73
 K [149]: 1 78

Here's a more concrete question:

> Is it true that the $d$-dimensional homology groups of $K(p)$ for $d > 1$ are always trivial?

Comment: "The primary motivation for this question...." Was that a pun?

Comment: Gerry: sadly, yes. I fear that my sense of humor is progressively deteriorating...

Comment: This way of constructing complexes must be interesting for sequences of integers other than primes, too!

Comment: @David: you mean like this? http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5704

Comment: Perhaps someone would like to turn the digraph mentioned in this answer
 http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72040/how-many-sequences-of-rational-squares-are-there-all-of-whose-differences-are-al/72145#72145 
 into a cell complex?  Of course, I'll settle for an answer to the questions instead.  Gerhard "Has Complex Around Doing Homology" Paseman, 2012.08.05

Comment: 1. Have you computed the distribution of these values for Cramer random primes? One might hope it be similar. 2. Is it clear whether the infinite complex is connected? I guess 2 is disconnected from the odd primes. Are those the only components of the infinite complex? Is it clear for Cramer primes?

Comment: Will: Sorry, but I don't know what Cramer Primes are, and googling has not yet helped. So the answer to your first question is certainly no. I'm not sure about connectedness (minus that pesky "2"), the only theorem I could think of using is Green Tao and that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I heard about them in the comments to this mathoverflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103187/random-pseudoprimes-vs-primes

Comment: Will: I see. Why do you think this would capture anything of interest in the present context? The second graph in the question that you linked to shows that the count of twin pseudoprimes doesn't even approximate the count of twin primes, and surely twin (blahs) is a degenerate simple case of (blahs) in arithmetic progression... Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Are the entries with $b_0 = 4$ errors? The vertex 17 in K[17] is connected via 5-11-17, and 41 in K[41] is connected via 17-29-41.

Comment: Zack: yeah, that's my mistake. I ran the code up till 997 and only built maximal progressions, so the 5-11-17 didn't get inserted until step 29, thanks to 5-11-17-23-29. I'll re-run once I fix up the code and edit the betti numbers tomorrow. Thanks! 

Comment: @Vel Nias: in contributions to the question mentioned by Will Sawin it is explained or at least hinted at why that specific rand. mod. does not capture this. But, there are other (similar) random models that are widely believed to predict the count of APs of primes. (See eg the intro of the paper of Green-Tao "Linear equations in primes" mentioned there, this is not the paper containing what is typically called the Green-Tao Theorem but a later development.)  Perhaps also the following question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57377/  and things linked from there are interesting for you. 

Comment: Regarding connectedness of the inf. complex: if I did not overlook something stupid, it is 'clear' (in the sense that 'everybody' believes it but nobody can prove it) that for any tow odd primes q1,q2 there will be a prime p (indeed infinitely many) such that q1,p and q2,p can each be completed to a 3-AP of primes. In other words for q1,q2 fixed there will be a prime p such that 2p -q1 and 2p -q2 are both prime. More generally any system of linear equations is believed to be solvable 'in the primes', except if there is a 'local' obstruction (congr. or size), and for some this can be shown.

Comment: I think there might be another error in your code, or I've misunderstood the construction of "add all faces" (I took it to mean all lower faces, not just the next dimension down). In K[43], 43 is adjacent to 3 (via 3-23-43), and also to 7 and 31 (via 7-19-31-43). 3 is adjacent to 31 (via 3-17-31) and of course to 7, so both (3, 7, 43) and (3, 31, 43) form non-trivial loops, so that $b_1 = 8$, since the 6 loops from K[37] remain in K[43]. It might be that the program is only looking at three term APs, since this is the first place where a 4-AP is necessary.

Comment: This might be obvious, but Betti-1 is non-decreasing. If there are three vertices (say $a, b, c$) in $K[m]$ such that each pair is in an arithmetic sequence, but no sequence bounded by $m$ contains all three, then no sequence ever contains all three. The common difference of such a sequence would be a divisor of $\gcd(b-a, c-b)$, and so would contain a subsequence of at least three terms beginning at $a$ and ending at $c$, which would appear in $K[m]$.

Comment: This is really cool. I had a look at the Björner paper and didn't quite grok it, so I posted a followup question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104149/how-do-facts-about-the-homotopy-type-of-cell-complexes-shed-light-on-analytic-num

Comment: My intention with using a random model of primes would be to compare the behavior of the actual primes to the random model. For instance: Is the asymptotic rate of the growth of $b_1$ actually the same, or faster, or slower?

Comment: Dear Zack, how are you sure that the new cycles created by the introduction of 43 are not related via the boundary of a 2-chain to each other or the old cycles? That is, why are all the 8 cycles you mention in K[43] necessarily non-homologous? In any case, I have modified the question to indicate that not only the codimension-1 facets, but all faces and sub-faces must be inserted into the simplicial

Comment: Ah yes, of course the two I wrote down are homologous, via 3-7-11, 3-11-19, and (the face I neglected) 19-31-43.

Comment: On 3-APs see also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34197/are-all-primes-in-a-pap-3

Comment: It seems to me it would make more sense to let your definition do what it says for all d, and put in all edges between vertices (because any pair of primes is an AP.)  Then as far as the AP goes, you are in a situation reminiscent of the work of Matt Kahle and his collaborators; a triple of vertices in K(p) is filled in with a 2-simplex with probability about c/p, and he can tell you what the right guess about homology groups is in this case. 

Comment: Jordan: I did toy with that idea but had no clue what the $c$ in your $c/p$ should be. I'm a huge fan of Matt's work, and would love to be able to apply it here. 

Comment: If I understand correctly the preceeding discussion, this c is known (or at least knowable) by a classical result of Chowla and Van der Corput on the number of primes in 3-AP. Unfortunately I do not find the actual value with this type of scaling and not sure if I get the rescaling correct on-the-fly. I vaguely believe (but if it is relevant please recheck) it is 1.32.../4 where the 1.32... is the one to be found for example on the slides of Green (page 5 and 6) of his 2006 ICM talk https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~bjg23/papers/icm-handout.pdf  (ADDED: specializing Ex 8, in G&T is another poss.)

Comment: Sorry the above constant is off. While I am meanwhile more confident that the count of the 3-APs up to p is about (1.32.../4)  p^2/(log p)^3 I took the total numer of 2-simplexes as about (p/log p)^3 [so ordered] but it should be unordered (or so I think) for an extra 1/6 . So then the fraction of 2-simplexes that are present should be c/p with c = (3/2) 1.32...  

Comment: Quid: thank you for this information. I will run tests to see if the random simplicial complexes have similar statistics and update when I have results.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. 
In fact, for $p = 435052917615787$, this will absolutely be false, as the second homology group will not vanish.

Note that a 2-dimensional "hole" in your complex is a 3-simplex all of whose faces are 2-simplices in $K(p)$, i.e. 4 primes such that each 3 of them lie in some arithmetic progression.

Of course, you would suspect that such a thing is plausible, and with some effort construct an example.
Here's why this number works:

Consider $p = 398936189798617$. Then, if $d = 2124513401010$, one sees that $p+d$ is not a prime, while $p+2d,p+3d,\ldots,p+15d$ are all primes. Here $p+15d = 435052917615787$ is the prime for which we consider the complex.

In fact, the numbers were taken from the AP-k records at http://primerecords.dk/aprecords.htm#minimal, and $p+2d$ is just a beginning of an AP-23.

Now, one sees immediately that $p, p+6d, p+10d$ form a simplex, as it is a subsequence of the arithmetic progression of primes $p, p+2d, p+4d, p+6d, p+10d$.

Similarly, $p, p+6d, p+15d$ form a simplex, as do $p, p+10d, p+15d$ and $p+6d, p+10d, p+15d$. These come from sequences with differences $3d$, $5d$, and $d$ respectively.

However, $p,p+6d,p+10d,p+15d$ can only form a simplex if they all lie in some arithmetic progression of primes. But then its difference must divide $d$, contradicting the fact that $p+d$ is not prime.

Comment: Thanks! The numbers involved are huge. So maybe this is also a good candidate answer to the big list question somewhere on this site asking about "eventual counterexamples"

Comment: This of course leads to the (harder) question: what is the smallest $p$ for which the second homology group of $K(p)$ is nontrivial?